# How to write block in IRB?

Tags: ruby, irb

For example, I want to implement this code in IRB, but it has single-line input so I can get how to write block there.

```
a = [3, 2, 1]
a[3] = a[2] - 1

a.each do |elt|
  print elt+1
end
```

Comment: You obviously haven't tried doing what you're asking. IRB is an interactive Ruby, and yes, it's line-oriented, but it's plenty smart to recognize your input as the beginning of a block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Oh you mean IRB)*

If you enter something that will be on multiple lines, ruby will wait until the final `end` is completed before running the code:

```
irb(main):001:0> def dostuff
irb(main):002:1>   puts "things"
irb(main):003:1> end
=> :dostuff
irb(main):004:0> dostuff
things
=> nil
irb(main):005:0>
```

As you can see the number at the prompt changes depending on how deep the block-level is.